# Pycharm Community 2017.1 - Unable to get the virutalenv interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv

My goal is to add the virtualenv interpreter in pychar
I installed pycharm community edition 2017.1 on ubuntu 14.04. I have virtualenv running using the command

```
$source /opt/e360/hello/py_27_env/bin/activate
```

when I try to add the virtual env using settings->project Interpreter . I can see the /usr/bin/python2.7 and /usr/bin/python3.4 python versions. 
when trying to add interpreter for /opt/e360/hello/py_27_env/bin/activate I get the error message

"***The selected file is not a valid home for python SDK***"

Please suggest if I am doing anything wrong

Comment: Point to bin/python2.7 or python binary not bin/activate.

Comment: Thank you . This helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't set the python interpreter to the `activate` file, you need to set it to the python binary file in that folder. Should be something in like this:

```
 /opt/e360/hello/py_27_env/bin/python2.7
```

Comment: Thank you , this helped me. I have accepted this as the solution.